# Why does this rotate method give the image dead space? OpenCV

Tags: ios, image, opencv, rotation

I am using this method to rotate a `cvMat`, whenever I run it I get back a rotated image however there is a lot of deadspace below it.

```
void rotate(cv::Mat& src, double angle, cv::Mat& dst)
{
    int len = std::max(src.cols, src.rows);
    cv::Point2f pt(len/2., len/2.);
    cv::Mat r = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(pt, angle, 1.0);

    cv::warpAffine(src, dst, r, cv::Size(len, len));

}
```

When given this image:

[image]

I get this image:

[image]

The image has been rotated but as you can see some extra pixels have been added, how can I only rotate the original image and not add any extra pixels?

Method call:

`rotate(src, skew, res);`
`res` being `dst`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **mayank-baddi** said you have to use  output image size same as the input to resolve this, and my answer is based on your comment above `How can I avoid adding the black area?` after wrapAffine,

So you have to do,

- Create white image little bigger than your source, and it will depend on your skew angle, here I used 50 pixel.

  ```
  int extend=50;
  Mat tmp(src.rows+2*extend,src.cols+2*extend,src.type(),Scalar::all(255));
  ```
- Copy the source to above using ROI

  ```
  Rect ROI(extend,extend,src.cols,src.rows);
  src.copyTo(tmp(ROI));
  ```
- Now rotate  `tmp` instead of  `src`

  ```
  rotate(tmp, skew, res); res being dst.
  ```
- Crop back the final image from rotated result using the same ROI.

  ```
   Mat crop=res(ROI);  
   imshow("crop",crop);
  ```

[image]

Comment: Since `extend` is based off skew angle how could I make it work for different skew angles?

Comment: @Nick See the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22041699/rotate-an-image-without-cropping-in-opencv-in-c/22042434#22042434

Answer (score 2):

You have to define the output image size while using `warpAffine` transform.
Here you are defining the size as `cv::Size(len, len)` where `len` is max of height and width.

```
cv::warpAffine(src, dst, r, cv::Size(len, len));
```

Define/calculate the size of the final image accordingly.

Comment: Ok I replaced `cv::Size(len, len))` with `src.size()` and have been getting good results. This is what I am getting now: http://i.imgur.com/W6T3yoJ.png  How can I avoid adding the black area?  Thanks