# Detect and fix text skew by rotating image

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Is there a way (using something like OpenCV) to detect text skew and correct it by rotating the image? Pretty much like this?

[image]

[image]

Rotating an image seems easy enough if you know the angle, but for the images I'm processing, I wont...it will need to be detected somehow.

Comment: http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/10/opencv-rotation-deskewing/

Comment: @Haris isn't that more for lines of text? I dont feel like it would be robust enough to handle this

Comment: It will work for the image like you provided above, as it's something like, locate all white pixel->find rotated rect for located point->rotate etc...See the result I got for the above image  http://i.stack.imgur.com/mxyRK.jpg

Comment: @Haris I tried http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/10/opencv-bounding-box-skew-angle/ and combined it with the post after but not much luck

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on your above comment, here is the code based on the tutorial [here](http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/10/opencv-rotation-deskewing/), working fine for the above image,

**Source**

[image]

**Rotated**

[image]

```
 Mat src=imread("text.png",0);
 Mat thr,dst;
 threshold(src,thr,200,255,THRESH_BINARY_INV);
 imshow("thr",thr);

  std::vector<cv::Point> points;
  cv::Mat_<uchar>::iterator it = thr.begin<uchar>();
  cv::Mat_<uchar>::iterator end = thr.end<uchar>();
  for (; it != end; ++it)
    if (*it)
      points.push_back(it.pos());

  cv::RotatedRect box = cv::minAreaRect(cv::Mat(points));
  cv::Mat rot_mat = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(box.center, box.angle, 1);

  //cv::Mat rotated(src.size(),src.type(),Scalar(255,255,255));
  Mat rotated;
  cv::warpAffine(src, rotated, rot_mat, src.size(), cv::INTER_CUBIC);
 imshow("rotated",rotated);
```

> 

**Edit:**

Also see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23147752/why-does-this-rotate-method-give-the-image-dead-space-opencv/23149915#23149915) , might be helpful.

Answer (score 8):

Here's an implementation of the [Projection Profile Method algorithm for skew angle estimation](http://www.cvc.uab.es/%7Ebagdanov/pubs/ijdar98.pdf). Various angle points are projected into an accumulator array where the skew angle can be defined as the angle of projection within a search interval that maximizes alignment. The idea is to rotate the image at various angles and generate a histogram of pixels for each iteration. To determine the skew angle, we compare the maximum difference between peaks and using this skew angle, rotate the image to correct the skew.

---

**Input**

[image]

**Result**

[image]

> Skew angle: -5

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import interpolation as inter

def correct_skew(image, delta=1, limit=5):
    def determine_score(arr, angle):
        data = inter.rotate(arr, angle, reshape=False, order=0)
        histogram = np.sum(data, axis=1, dtype=float)
        score = np.sum((histogram[1:] - histogram[:-1]) ** 2, dtype=float)
        return histogram, score

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1] 

    scores = []
    angles = np.arange(-limit, limit + delta, delta)
    for angle in angles:
        histogram, score = determine_score(thresh, angle)
        scores.append(score)

    best_angle = angles[scores.index(max(scores))]

    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    center = (w // 2, h // 2)
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, best_angle, 1.0)
    corrected = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (w, h), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, \
            borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)

    return best_angle, corrected

if __name__ == '__main__':
    image = cv2.imread('1.png')
    angle, corrected = correct_skew(image)
    print('Skew angle:', angle)
    cv2.imshow('corrected', corrected)
    cv2.waitKey()
```

**Note:** You may have to adjust the `delta` or `limit` values depending on the image. The `delta` value controls iteration step, it will iterate up until the `limit` which controls the maximum angle. This method is straightforward by iteratively checking each angle + `delta` and currently only works to correct skew in the range of +/- 5 degrees. If you need to correct at a larger angle, adjust the `limit` value.

Comment: ``def determine_score(arr, angle)`` is called [Projection profile method](https://towardsdatascience.com/pre-processing-in-ocr-fc231c6035a7) [image](https://miro.medium.com/max/610/1*b76nvNcSUNwMnBdm1rd7WQ.gif)

Answer (score 2):

I would provide javacv for your reference.

```
package com.test13;

import org.opencv.core.*;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;

public class EdgeDetection {

    static{ System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); }

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception{      
        Mat src = Imgcodecs.imread("src//data//inclined_text.jpg");
        Mat src_gray = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(src, src_gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        Imgcodecs.imwrite("src//data//inclined_text_src_gray.jpg", src_gray);

        Mat output = new Mat();
        Core.bitwise_not(src_gray, output);
        Imgcodecs.imwrite("src//data//inclined_text_output.jpg", output);

        Mat points = Mat.zeros(output.size(),output.type());  
        Core.findNonZero(output, points);   

        MatOfPoint mpoints = new MatOfPoint(points);    
        MatOfPoint2f points2f = new MatOfPoint2f(mpoints.toArray());
        RotatedRect box = Imgproc.minAreaRect(points2f);

        Mat src_squares = src.clone();
        Mat rot_mat = Imgproc.getRotationMatrix2D(box.center, box.angle, 1);
        Mat rotated = new Mat(); 
        Imgproc.warpAffine(src_squares, rotated, rot_mat, src_squares.size(), Imgproc.INTER_CUBIC);
        Imgcodecs.imwrite("src//data//inclined_text_squares_rotated.jpg",rotated);    
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working, for some images it will rotate them to 90 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun main(){
    val bmp:Bitmap? = null //Any bitmap (if you are working with bitmap)
    var mRgba = Mat() // else you can direct use MAT on onCameraFrame 
    val mGray = Mat()
    val bmp32: Bitmap = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp32, mRgba)
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mGray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    mRgba = makeOrientationCorrection(mRgba,mGray)// here actual magic starts
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mGray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    val bmpOutX = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        mRgba.cols(),
        mRgba.rows(),
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    )
    Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba, bmpOutX)
    binding.imagePreview.setImageBitmap(bmpOutX!!)
}

private fun makeOrientationCorrection(mRGBA:Mat, mGRAY:Mat):Mat{
    val dst = Mat()
    val cdst = Mat()
    val cdstP: Mat
    Imgproc.Canny(mGRAY, dst, 50.0, 200.0, 3, false)
    Imgproc.cvtColor(dst, cdst, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    cdstP = cdst.clone()

    val linesP = Mat()
    Imgproc.HoughLinesP(dst, linesP, 1.0, Math.PI/180, 50, 50.0, 10.0)

    var biggestLineX1 = 0.0
    var biggestLineY1 = 0.0
    var biggestLineX2 = 0.0
    var biggestLineY2 = 0.0
    var biggestLine = 0.0
    for (x in 0 until linesP.rows()) {
        val l = linesP[x, 0]

        Imgproc.line(
            cdstP, org.opencv.core.Point(l[0], l[1]),
            org.opencv.core.Point(l[2], l[3]),
            Scalar(0.0, 0.0, 255.0), 3, Imgproc.LINE_AA, 0)
    }

    for (x in 0 until linesP.rows()) {
        val l = linesP[x, 0]
        val x1 = l[0]
        val y1 = l[1]
        val x2 = l[2]
        val y2 = l[3]
        val lineHeight = sqrt(((x2 - x1).pow(2.0)) + ((y2 - y1).pow(2.0)))
        if(biggestLine<lineHeight){
            val angleOfRotationX1 = angleOf(PointF(x1.toFloat(),y1.toFloat()),PointF(x2.toFloat(),y2.toFloat()))
            Log.e("angleOfRotationX1","$angleOfRotationX1")
            if(angleOfRotationX1<45.0 || angleOfRotationX1>270.0){
                biggestLine = lineHeight
                if(angleOfRotationX1<45.0){
                    biggestLineX1 = x1
                    biggestLineY1 = y1
                    biggestLineX2 = x2
                    biggestLineY2 = y2
                }
                if(angleOfRotationX1>270.0){
                    biggestLineX1 = x2
                    biggestLineY1 = y2
                    biggestLineX2 = x1
                    biggestLineY2 = y1
                }
            }
        }
        if(x==linesP.rows()-1){
            Imgproc.line(
                cdstP, org.opencv.core.Point(biggestLineX1, biggestLineY1),
                org.opencv.core.Point(biggestLineX2, biggestLineY2),
                Scalar(255.0, 0.0, 0.0), 3, Imgproc.LINE_AA, 0)
        }
    }
    var angle = angleOf(PointF(biggestLineX1.toFloat(),biggestLineY1.toFloat()),PointF(biggestLineX2.toFloat(),biggestLineY2.toFloat()))
    Log.e("angleOfRotationX2","$angle")
    angle -= (angle * 2)
    return deskew(mRGBA,angle)
}

fun angleOf(p1: PointF, p2: PointF): Double {
    val deltaY = (p1.y - p2.y).toDouble()
    val deltaX = (p2.x - p1.x).toDouble()
    val result = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX))
    return if (result < 0) 360.0 + result else result
}

private fun deskew(src:Mat, angle:Double):Mat{
    val center = org.opencv.core.Point((src.width() / 2).toDouble(), (src.height() / 2).toDouble())
    val scaleBy = if(angle<0){
        1.0+((0.5*angle)/45)//max scale down by 0.50(50%) based on angle
    }else{
        1.0-((0.3*angle)/45)//max scale down by 0.50(50%) based on angle
    }

    Log.e("scaleBy",""+scaleBy)
    val rotImage = Imgproc.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, scaleBy)
    val size = Size(src.width().toDouble(), src.height().toDouble())
    Imgproc.warpAffine(src, src, rotImage, size, Imgproc.INTER_LINEAR + Imgproc.CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS)
    return src
}
```

Make sure you run this "makeOrientationCorrection()" method on another thread. otherwise, UI won't update for 2-5 sec.