# Python + OpenCV: OCR Image Segmentation

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to do OCR from this toy example of Receipts. Using Python 2.7 and OpenCV 3.1.

[image]

Grayscale + Blur + External Edge Detection + Segmentation of each area in the Receipts (for example "Category" to see later which one is marked -in this case cash-).

I find complicated when the image is "skewed" to be able to properly transform and then "automatically" segment each segment of the receipts.

Example:

[image]

Any suggestion?

The code below is an example to get until the edge detection, but when the receipt is like the first image. My issue is not the Image to text. Is the pre-processing of the image.

Any help more than appreciated! :)

```
import os;
os.chdir() # Put your own directory

import cv2 
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("Rent-Receipt.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (5, 5), 0)

#blurred  = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray,9,75,75)

# apply Canny Edge Detection
edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, 0, 20)

#Find external contour

(_,contours, _) = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A great tutorial on the first step you described is available at [pyimagesearch](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/01/build-kick-ass-mobile-document-scanner-just-5-minutes/) (and they have great tutorials in general)

In short, as described by Ella, you would have to use `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE`. A slightly more robust method would be to use `cv2.RETR_LIST` instead of `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL` and then sort the areas, as it should decently work even in white backgrounds/if the page inscribes a bigger shape in the background, etc.

Coming to the second part of your question, a good way to segment the characters would be to use the *Maximally stable extremal region extractor* available in OpenCV. A complete implementation in CPP is available [here](https://github.com/iitmcvg/OCR-Handwritten-Text/blob/master/Textsegmentation/charsegment.cpp) in a project I was helping out in recently. The Python implementation would go along the lines of (Code below works for OpenCV 3.0+. For the OpenCV 2.x syntax, check it up online)

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
mser = cv2.MSER_create()

#Resize the image so that MSER can work better
img = cv2.resize(img, (img.shape[1]*2, img.shape[0]*2))

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
vis = img.copy()

regions = mser.detectRegions(gray)
hulls = [cv2.convexHull(p.reshape(-1, 1, 2)) for p in regions[0]]
cv2.polylines(vis, hulls, 1, (0,255,0)) 

cv2.namedWindow('img', 0)
cv2.imshow('img', vis)
while(cv2.waitKey()!=ord('q')):
    continue
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This gives the output as

[image]

Now, to eliminate the false positives, you can simply cycle through the points in hulls, and calculate the perimeter (sum of distance between all adjacent points in hulls[i], where hulls[i] is a list of all points in one convexHull). If the perimeter is too large, classify it as not a character.

The diagnol lines across the image are coming because the border of the image is black. that can simply be removed by adding the following line as soon as the image is read (below line 7)

```
img = img[5:-5,5:-5,:]
```

which gives the output

[image]

Comment: Thanks @R. S. Nikhil Krishna !! If i use your code for the image (not skewed) of the receipt (see above in the question). I do not get a good segmentation. Question. which parameters should i tune? The convex hull? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @donpresente I've made the changes. The reason it was not detecting the characters was because the image size was too small. MSER requires significant spacing between characters. That can be achieved by simply resizing the images

Comment: Nikhil Krishna. I think we have a winner! :) any other advice on the segmentation? Because a "hand made" model could require to divde each character individually right? Should i force a grid on the text?

Comment: By a hand made model, do you mean manually tuned parameters? And a grid might be slightly problematic because the characters are not equal in size.

Answer (score 7):

The option on the top of my head requires the extractions of 4 corners of the skewed image. This is done by using `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE` instead of `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE` when finding contours. Afterwards, you could use `cv2.approxPolyDP` and hopefully remain with the 4 corners of the receipt (If all your images are like this one then there is no reason why it shouldn't work).

Now use `cv2.findHomography` and `cv2.wardPerspective` to rectify the image according to source points which are the 4 points extracted from the skewed image and destination points that should form a rectangle, for example the full image dimensions.

Here you could find code samples and more information: 
[OpenCV-Geometric Transformations of Images](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html)

Also this answer may be useful - [SO - Detect and fix text skew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23283532/detect-and-fix-text-skew)

EDIT: Corrected the second chain approx to `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE`.

Comment: thanks! and then how can you segment the text in the rectify image? (this is part of the question)

Comment: @donpresente You wrote "My issue is not the Image to text. Is the pre-processing of the image." Anyway, I am not capable to contribute much in the OCR part.

Comment: pre-processing for me would include image segmentation. I think the system will send the 50 points to you if no additional answer. Question, if you dont have contour, how your solution works?

Comment: Pre-processing does not generally include image segmentation. In this specific case, the image segmentation is the main processing step. Great answer @Elia!

Answer (score 3):

Preprocessing the image by converting the desired text in the foreground to black while turning unwanted background to white can help to improve OCR accuracy. In addition, removing the horizontal and vertical lines can improve results. Here's the preprocessed image after removing unwanted noise such as the horizontal/vertical lines. Note the removed border and table lines

[image]

```
import cv2

# Load in image, convert to grayscale, and threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find and remove horizontal lines
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (35,2))
detect_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_horizontal, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, (0,0,0), 3)

# Find and remove vertical lines
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,35))
detect_vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_vertical, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, (0,0,0), 3)

# Mask out unwanted areas for result
result = cv2.bitwise_and(image,image,mask=thresh)
result[thresh==0] = (255,255,255)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using Stroke Width Transform. Python 3 implementation of the algorithm is present here at [SWTloc](https://github.com/ag-ds-bubble/swtloc)

**EDIT : v2.0.0 onwards**

### Install the Library

```
pip install swtloc
```

### Transform The Image

```py
import swtloc as swt

imgpath = 'images/path_to_image.jpeg'
swtl = swt.SWTLocalizer(image_paths=imgpath)
swtImgObj = swtl.swtimages[0]
# Perform SWT Transformation with numba engine
swt_mat = swtImgObj.transformImage(text_mode='lb_df', gaussian_blurr=False, 
                                   minimum_stroke_width=3, maximum_stroke_width=12,
                                   maximum_angle_deviation=np.pi/2)
```

[image]

---

#### Localize Letters

```py
localized_letters = swtImgObj.localizeLetters(minimum_pixels_per_cc=10,
                                              localize_by='min_bbox')
```

[image]

---

#### Localize Words

```py
localized_words =  swtImgObj.localizeWords(localize_by='bbox')
```

[image]

---

There are multiple parameters in the of the `.transformImage`, `.localizeLetters` and `.localizeWords` function sthat you can play around with to get the desired results.

Full Disclosure : I am the author of this library

Comment: I like this library, fascinating stuff, thanks for sharing this!