# Detect and fix text rotation(90 degree)

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I just found the solution to [Detect and fix text skew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23362494/6279975) and related article [OpenCV - Rotation (Deskewing)](http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/10/opencv-rotation-deskewing/). But the solution is not work for some text rotated 90 degree.

I want to fix text rotated 90 degree like images below, [Detect and fix text skew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23362494/6279975) solution works for second image but first image is not work.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the rotation angle that you get when you run the code??

Comment: @Mayank -89, I updated my question, the solution is not work for first image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect text orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783061/detect-text-orientation)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Python OCR (pytesseract) to read the text from image, once you extracted the string, then search for some specific keywords/Stopwords in the text. If they not exist rotate for 90 degree and run OCR again. If they exist stop rotation.

This can rotate 90,270,180 degree shifted images.

Note: This is only applicable for text images.

Answer (score 0):

this code rotates by multiples of 90 degrees angles

```
import pytesseract
orientation = pytesseract.image_to_osd(tempname, output_type='dict')['orientation']  
if orientation in [90, 180, 270]:
   image = image.rotate(int(orientation), expand=True)
```