# OpenCv rotate text image

Tags: c#, opencv

help me rotate text image, i want the text to be smooth all the examples that are written in python.
My code.

```
   var src = Cv2.ImRead("NzGFw.png");
        var gray = new Mat();
        Cv2.CvtColor(src, gray, ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY);
        var output = new Mat();
        Cv2.BitwiseNot(gray, output);
        Mat points = Mat.Zeros(output.Size(), output.Type());
        Cv2.FindNonZero(output, points);
        var box = Cv2.MinAreaRect(points);
        Mat squares = src.Clone();
        Mat rot = Cv2.GetRotationMatrix2D(box.Center,  box.Angle, 1);
        Mat rotated = new Mat();
        Cv2.WarpAffine(squares, rotated, rot, squares.Size(), InterpolationFlags.Cubic);
        Cv2.ImWrite("inclined_text_squares_rotated.jpg", rotated);[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. please clarify.

Comment: And if you want help you should post all the resources that your program needs, in this case, the unprocessed original image. How can we help without the resources you are using?

Comment: I do text recognition, I get a picture, but the text on the picture is not smooth and the tesseract does not recognize it through openCvShapr, I try to rotate the text in the picture so that it becomes smooth, all the examples that are on python.

Comment: I need to do like here https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/20/text-skew-correction-opencv-python / but all the examples are in python or like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23283532/detect-and-fix-text-skew-by-rotating-image

Comment: Here example http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/09/opencv-detect-skew-angle/   but  C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public static float CalcAngle(Mat image)
    {
        double angle = 0;
        var img = new Mat();
        var size = image.Size();
        Cv2.CvtColor(image, img, ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY);
        Cv2.BitwiseNot(img, img);
        var lines = Cv2.HoughLinesP(img, 1, Math.PI / 180, 100, size.Width / 2f, 10);

        foreach (var line in lines)
            img.Line(line.P1, line.P2, Scalar.White, 1, LineTypes.AntiAlias, 0);

        for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            angle += Math.Atan2(lines[i].P2.Y - lines[i].P1.Y, lines[i].P2.X - lines[i].P1.X);

        angle = angle / lines.Length;
        return (float)((angle * 180) / Math.PI);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe add some more info on your answer to clarify what you offer as an answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I needed to implement the hava algorithm in C#, i.e. determine the angle of the text. I showed you the links, did you look at them?