# OpenCV rotated image has incorrect shape when displayed

Tags: opencv

I rotated the image from the left to the image on the right using

```
image = cv2.warpAffine(image, R, dst_size, flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```

where `dst_size` is `(547, 363)`, and I've modified R so that the original image should fit in the new dimensions.
I show the image with `cv2.imshow('rect post-rotation', img)` to show the image on the right. You can see that it appears clipped to a size of `(363, 547)`, even though when I print out the img shape, I get `(547, 363, 3)`.

Why does the shape of the image not reflect the shape of the displayed image?

[image]

Comment: Hi, see the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22041699/rotate-an-image-without-cropping-in-opencv-in-c/22042434#22042434

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set the destination size to the rotated size ie:

```
   cv::Size dst_size(imOrig.size().height,imOrig.size().width);
```

alternatively you can use transpose and flip for 90 degree rotation:

```
   cv::Mat imRot90 = imOrig.t();   
   cv::flip(imRot90 ,imRot90 ,1);
```

cheers

Comment: I did set the destination size to be the rotated size.

Comment: are you sure as the co-ordinates of Size, size(x,y), are the other way around to image(y,x), so it is easy to set it wrong.  What happens if you set it the other way around?