# OpenCV Python : rotate image without cropping sides

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, rotation

Imagine I have these images :

[image: ttps://i.stack.imgur.com/jjRfe.png]

I want the image from left to be rotated like the image of the middle, not the right one. How do I do this using Python and OpenCV. I looked at `getRotationMatrix2D` and `warpAffine` but the examples about it transform my image to the right one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotate an image without cropping in OpenCV in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22041699/rotate-an-image-without-cropping-in-opencv-in-c)

Comment: See https://pyimagesearch.com/2017/01/02/rotate-images-correctly-with-opencv-and-python/

Answer (score 49):

This is by far the best solution i have found for rotating images while avoiding cropping the image.

[Rotate an image without cropping in OpenCV in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22041699/rotate-an-image-without-cropping-in-opencv-in-c/33564950#33564950)

```
import cv2

def rotate_image(mat, angle):
    """
    Rotates an image (angle in degrees) and expands image to avoid cropping
    """
    
    height, width = mat.shape[:2] # image shape has 3 dimensions
    image_center = (width/2, height/2) # getRotationMatrix2D needs coordinates in reverse order (width, height) compared to shape
    
    rotation_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(image_center, angle, 1.)
    
    # rotation calculates the cos and sin, taking absolutes of those.
    abs_cos = abs(rotation_mat[0,0]) 
    abs_sin = abs(rotation_mat[0,1])
    
    # find the new width and height bounds
    bound_w = int(height * abs_sin + width * abs_cos)
    bound_h = int(height * abs_cos + width * abs_sin)
    
    # subtract old image center (bringing image back to origo) and adding the new image center coordinates
    rotation_mat[0, 2] += bound_w/2 - image_center[0]
    rotation_mat[1, 2] += bound_h/2 - image_center[1]
    
    # rotate image with the new bounds and translated rotation matrix
    rotated_mat = cv2.warpAffine(mat, rotation_mat, (bound_w, bound_h))
    return rotated_mat
```

You can add checks to avoid some calculations when the angles are 90*n, but this function will work for any angle as is.

---

Taking advantage of `numpy` vectorization

```
def rotate_image(img, angle):
    size_reverse = np.array(img.shape[1::-1]) # swap x with y
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(tuple(size_reverse / 2.), angle, 1.)
    MM = np.absolute(M[:,:2])
    size_new = MM @ size_reverse
    M[:,-1] += (size_new - size_reverse) / 2.
    return cv2.warpAffine(img, M, tuple(size_new.astype(int)))
```

Comment: This is more general than the OP asked for, but it's a great solution and I think it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Use "borderMode=" flag on warpAffine to control how borders are filled (if any are present in result).

Comment: bound_w = int(height * abs_sin + width * abs_cos)

Is it supposed to use height here as first parameter? Should be width?

Comment: notice that `cv2` contains a `numpy` alias so no extra import is needed: for ex `MM = cv2.numpy.absolute(M[:,:2])`

Answer (score 25):

If you only care about 90 degree rotations numpy instead. It's much easier and works on opencv input:

```
import numpy as np
rotated_image = np.rot90(im)
```

Comment: Some functions (cv.rectangle for example) will not work after this.

Comment: You can fix with: np.ascontiguousarray(np.rot90(im))  or: np.rot90(im).copy()

Answer (score 15):

As I don't know your code I still would guess that using the `imutils.rotate_bound`function will solve the problem. E.g.: `rotate = imutils.rotate_bound(image, angle)`

Comment: Is imutils part of OpenCV or should I add it?

Comment: You will need to install it via `pip install imutils`, and to import it of course `import imutils` into your python code

Comment: Ok Thank you, I will try that !

Comment: Oddly enough, that method assumes you want the picture in portrait mode. i.e. giving `0.0` as the rotation angle will make sure the longer dimension is now the height, even if that means rotating it up to 90 degrees.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative from `ndimage.rotate` from [SciPy](https://scipy.org/)

[Related documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.rotate.html)

```
from scipy.ndimage import rotate as rotate_image

#rotation angle in degree
rotated_img1 = rotate_image(img,90)
```

[image]

```
rotated_img2 = rotate_image(img,-110)
```

[image]

```
rotated_img3 = rotate_image(img,-45)
```

[image]

```
# angles extending beyond 360 are calculated appropriately:
rotated_img4 = rotate_image(img,390)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is the easiest way to rotate image frames by using cv2.rotate(frame,rotateCode = 1) and rescale or resizing by using cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH and cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT of the frame.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(2)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640) # You can change frame width by chaning number.

    cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480) # You can change frame height by chaning number.

    ret, frame = cam.read()

    new_frame=cv2.rotate(frame,rotateCode = 1)
```

## You can enter rotateCode= 0 or 1 or 2. Depends on your rotation. It's gonna give you 0 or 90 or 180 or 270 angles

```
    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',new_frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Hopefully, it with help you.

Answer (score 2):

While this question was asked for CV2, you can do this with python's native image library.

```
rotate_degrees = -90
img = Image.open(input_file_path)
img2 = img.rotate(rotate_degrees, expand=True)
img2.save(output_file_path)
```

If you leave out `expand=True` in the rotate command you will get a result that looks like OP's right hand photo.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use padding as well, that is, add borders to the sides of the image, then rotate it to avoid cropping from the original image.

```
def rotate_im(image, angle)
    image_height = image.shape[0]
    image_width = image.shape[1]
    diagonal_square = (image_width*image_width) + (
        image_height* image_height
    )
    #
    diagonal = round(sqrt(diagonal_square))
    padding_top = round((diagonal-image_height) / 2)
    padding_bottom = round((diagonal-image_height) / 2)
    padding_right = round((diagonal-image_width) / 2)
    padding_left = round((diagonal-image_width) / 2)
    padded_image = cv2.copyMakeBorder(image,
                                      top=padding_top,
                                      bottom=padding_bottom,
                                      left=padding_left,
                                      right=padding_right,
                                      borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,
                                      value=0
            )
    padded_height = padded_image.shape[0]
    padded_width = padded_image.shape[1]
    transform_matrix = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(
                (padded_height/2,
                 padded_width/2), # center
                angle, # angle
      1.0) # scale
    rotated_image = cv2.warpAffine(padded_image,
                                   transform_matrix,
                                   (diagonal, diagonal),
                                   flags=cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)
    return rotated_image
```

Answer (score 0):

its simple no need of any warpaffine or any calculation check this code out

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2

angle = -90
scale = 1.0

while True:
    img = ImageGrab.grab()
    img_np = np.array(img)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    new = cv2.rotate(frame,rotateCode = 0)# this is the line to rotate the image
    true = cv2.resize(new, (0,0), fx = 0.6, fy = 0.6) # with fxand fy u can control the size
    cv2.imshow('output', true)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```