# OpenCV image rotation

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, image-rotation

I have an image `full_image_map` which I have rotated by a certain `angle` using the following code:

```
Mat rotated_full_map_image;
Point2f src_center(full_map_image.cols/2.0F, full_map_image.rows/2.0F);    
Mat rot_mat = getRotationMatrix2D(src_center, angle, 1.0);
warpAffine(full_map_image, rotated_full_map_image, rot_mat, full_map_image.size());
```

I have also found the coordinates of a point in the rotated image using this:

```
Point rotated_centre;
Point2f p(some_x,some_y);  
rotated_centre.x = rot_mat.at<double>(0,0)*p.x + rot_mat.at<double>(0,1)*p.y + rot_mat.at<double>(0,2);
rotated_centre.y = rot_mat.at<double>(1,0)*p.x + rot_mat.at<double>(1,1)*p.y + rot_mat.at<double>(1,2);
```

However, my original image `full_image_map` is much more tall than it is wide. So when I rotate it by say 90 degrees and specify the size of the rotated image to be `full_map_image.size()`, most of the rotated image is cut off since it tries to fit it only in that mentioned size. This is similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22041699/rotate-an-image-without-cropping-in-opencv-in-c).

My question: how can I properly perform this rotation by any given angle and still use the same method to find the coordinates of a point in the rotated image? I am using opencv with c++.

Comment: You should be able to use the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24352524/4228275) of the [question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22041699/rotate-an-image-without-cropping-in-opencv-in-c): if you multiply the point with the rotation_matrix `rot` you should be fine.

Comment: if you want a solution for any homography transformation (not only rotation), create a vector with all 4 corners of the original image, transform them with  the homography, compute bounding box and adjust the homography according to the bbox position.