# Moving cv::RotatedRect in the same position after rotating a cv::Mat without cropping

Tags: c++, opencv

I've currently trouble to understand what's necessary to transform a `cv::RotatedRect` after rotating an image without cropping using the following code by Lars Schillingmann in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22041699/rotate-an-image-without-cropping-in-opencv-in-c/24352524#24352524).

Here's the code he provided as answer:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

int main()
{
    cv::Mat src = cv::imread("im.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
    double angle = -45;

    // get rotation matrix for rotating the image around its center in pixel coordinates
    cv::Point2f center((src.cols-1)/2.0, (src.rows-1)/2.0);
    cv::Mat rot = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0);
    // determine bounding rectangle, center not relevant
    cv::Rect2f bbox = cv::RotatedRect(cv::Point2f(), src.size(), angle).boundingRect2f();
    // adjust transformation matrix
    rot.at<double>(0,2) += bbox.width/2.0 - src.cols/2.0;
    rot.at<double>(1,2) += bbox.height/2.0 - src.rows/2.0;

    cv::Mat dst;
    cv::warpAffine(src, dst, rot, bbox.size());
    cv::imwrite("rotated_im.png", dst);

    return 0;
}
```

In my case, I've a `cv::RotatedRect` which matches a certain position in the `src` image. This `cv::RotatedRect` should match the same postion after the transformation/rotation was applied to the `src` mat. Currently, I struggle with doing it the right way.

From what I know, to rotate a `cv::RotatedRect`, it's only necessary to directly modify the members of the structure e.g. `angle`. I'm quite sure that I only have to modify the center, but the new position is always a bit off from the expected location. I initially expected that I only have to add the difference between `bbox` and `src` dimensions to get what I'm looking for but it turns out to be not the case (inlcuding the rotation of course).

```
connected_components[i].center.x += ...
connected_components[i].center.y += ...
cv::RotatedRect newRect(connected_components[i].center, connected_components[i].size, connected_components[i].angle- median);
```

Comment: As of OpenCV3.2 ,   `cv::rotate(image, image, cv::ROTATE_180);` or 
 `ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE` , `ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE` ...

Comment: I don't know how this should help...

Comment: will angle be 0 after rotation?  x and y will be moved according to the "adjust transformation ..." lines. You could also transform the rotatedRect corner points with cv::perspectiveTransform and compute minAreaRect on the result.

Comment: The angle will be close to zero but not exactly. I estimate text lines in an swt image and perform a rotation according to the angle.

Comment: Could you provide an example of your suggestion please? A simple formula would be less expensive but I can fix that later.

Comment: I'm writing from mobile, so hard to provide code. rotatedRect has class members to get the 4 corner points. Add them to a vector<cv::Point2f> and use the function cv::perspectiveTransform  to warp them according to your transformation (you have to add a [0,0,1] row to your transformation, though, because of affine->perspective). Afterwards you have the transformed rotatedRect's corner points and can use cv::minAreaRect to compute the new rotatedRect from them.

Comment: Thank you. See my own answer to the question. This is quite similar to your suggestion but only using cv::transform().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite simple. We can reuse the transformation matrix for a point transform using `cv::transform`. Sample code is below:

```
        cv::Point2f points[4];
        connected_components[i].points(points);
        std::vector<cv::Point2f> old_points;
        old_points.insert(old_points.begin(), std::begin(points), std::end(points));
        std::vector<cv::Point2f> new_points;
        cv::transform(old_points, new_points, rotation_matrix);
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
            cv::line(dest, new_points[j], new_points[(j + 1) % 4], cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0));
        }
```